# Can we inherit code from one namespace to another

Tags: c#, inheritance, namespaces

Lets say I have one namespace named `first_namespace` in which I have a class named `first_class` in that class  I have a function named `first_function`. I have one more `second_namespace` in which I have a class `second_class` in the main method of `second_class` I have created an object

```
second_class sc = new second_class();
//now I wont be able to call firt_function by using the object sc
```

but if I create object of first class that is in first namespace like this:

```
first_class fc = new first_class();
fc.first_function();//it works
```

so my question is: can we call it inheritance ? if not then what I call it ?

Comment: Can you post some more code to clarify your question?

Comment: Inheritance works across namespaces, if that's your question... I can't really tell.

Comment: Aside from everything else, please learn to follow .NET naming conventions. It'll make your questions much easier to read for .NET developers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When your question has been answered, please leave it up in case anybody else has the same question as you, and click the green checkmark next to one of the answers below to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can inheritance and namespaces are completely separate concepts.

Inheritance lets you derive a child class from any none sealed object.

A namespace is simply a conceptual container for logically locating and grouping code.

Hope this helps

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Any method in C# belongs to a class (or struct). You can only call the method on an object of the correct class type (also called an instance of the type).

This is not inheritance. It is one part of **object-oriented programming** that a method belongs to objects of a particular type (and so do not exist on objects of other types).